# Swiper carousel product

Tags: html, css, swiper.js, web-frontend

i would like to ask about my swiper script that i use so i need to make the pagination is showing at the bottom of product

here my style and script for changing the swiper

[overlap with pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmeBz.png)

```
<style>
 

  .swiper-button-next {
    position: absolute; /* Add this line to set the position property */
    /* Add additional styling as needed */
    right: -60px; /* Adjust the value as per your design */
    color: orange;
  }
  
  .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute; /* Add this line to set the position property */
    /* Add additional styling as needed */
    left: -60px; /* Adjust the value as per your design */
    color: orange;
  }
  .swiper-pagination {
    position: absolute; /* Add this line to set the position property */
    /* Add additional styling as needed */
    bottom: 60px; /* Adjust the value as per your design */
    color: orange;
  }

</style>


<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 10,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
      },
      1200: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

my coding for swiper html and php

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="swiper">
          <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="block-4 text-center">
                  <figure class="block-4-image">
                    <img src="../images/<?= $row['ProductImage'] ?>" alt="Image placeholder" class="img-fluid">
                  </figure>
                  <div class="block-4-text p-4">
                    <h3 class="small-title"><a href="shop-single.php?ProductID=<?= $row['ProductID'] ?>"><?= $row['ProductName'] ?></a></h3>
                    <p class="mb-0 small-description"><?= htmlspecialchars(substr($row['Description'], 0, 10)) ?></p>
                    <p class="text-primary font-weight-bold small-price">RM <?= $row['Price'] ?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

why the pagination is overlap with product
i hope you guys can help me

i already change the css to bottom = 20px